# Mailkit stream lots of messages and delete them

Tags: c#, imap, mailkit

I want to export gmail messages into files, message per file. What is the best strategy for this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < inbox.Count; i++)
   {
        var message = inbox.GetMessage(i);
        // export message
        inbox.AddFlags (i, MessageFlags.Deleted);
   }
```

My concern is if I delete message inside the loop, won't it disrupt the the order indexes.
I cannot use 2 separate loops for reading and deleting, because gmail is slow to read and if reading loop fails at some point, then I have to start the whole process all over again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With standard IMAP servers, setting the `\Deleted` flag on a message does not remove the message from the folder, it simply sets a flag which a future `EXPUNGE` command will use to decide which messages to purge.

That said, servers like GMail use non-standard behavior by default and so your concern is valid.

To avoid this type of problem, I would recommend using uids instead. I highly recommend avoiding the use of index based API's altogether.

```
var uids = folder.Search (SearchQuery.All);
foreach (var uid in uids) {
    var message = folder.GetMessage (uid);
    folder.AddFlags (uid, MessageFlags.Deleted);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I already implemented chunk import. Still your solution looks elegant.

Comment: Any idea how to do it for POP3? Not all POP3 supports UID. I intend to create library that fetch and delete for both POP3 and IMAP.

Comment: Pop3’s DELE command works just like setting the \Deleted flag on IMAP. The messages are not actually deleted until you logout.